# Use Java AlertDialog in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, android-alertdialog

I am working on a react-native application that uses the NearbyConnection API.
I don't want the connection to be automatically accepted.
The user should be able to accept or decline the connection.
I tried the code proposed by Google (code below)

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
      .setTitle("Accept connection to " + info.getEndpointName())
      .setMessage("Confirm the code matches on both devices: " + info.getAuthenticationDigits())
      .setPositiveButton(
          "Accept",
          (DialogInterface dialog, int which) ->
              // The user confirmed, so we can accept the connection.
              Nearby.getConnectionsClient(context)
                  .acceptConnection(endpointId, payloadCallback))
      .setNegativeButton(
          "Refuse",
          (DialogInterface dialog, int which) ->
              // The user canceled, so we should reject the connection.
              Nearby.getConnectionsClient(context).rejectConnection(endpointId))
      .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
      .show();
```

but it doesn't work (the application crashes at this level).
Is there a way to rewrite this code to be compatible with reat-native?
Or is it possible to execute a JS function and get the result in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get cross platform native alerts in react-native by just doing this below. Just import `Alert` from react-native.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const createTwoButtonAlert = () =>
    Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title",
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ]
    );

  const createThreeButtonAlert = () =>
    Alert.alert(
      "Alert Title",
      "My Alert Msg",
      [
        {
          text: "Ask me later",
          onPress: () => console.log("Ask me later pressed")
        },
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          onPress: () => console.log("Cancel Pressed"),
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") }
      ]
    );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title={"2-Button Alert"} onPress={createTwoButtonAlert} />
      <Button title={"3-Button Alert"} onPress={createThreeButtonAlert} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```